# Postgres, Как переименовать таблицу в случае её существования, а в случае её НЕ существования - создать новую

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица A , нужно в случае её существования переименовать её в B. 
В свою очередь если A не существует - создать новую B

Comment: В два запроса. Пробуем (IF EXISTS) переименовать, потом пробуем создать. Или запрашиваем наличие таблицы через метаданные БД, и в зависимости от результат делаем или переименование, или создание.

Comment: Какая версия Postgres у вас?

Answer (score 2):

Все хорошо в предыдущем ответе, кроме самого ответа на вопрос:
Как же проверить существование, тут есть два способа:

1) Использовать ANSI подход, через (`information_schema`), т.е.:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM   information_schema.tables 
WHERE  table_schema = 'schema_name'
AND    table_name = 'table_name'
);
```

2) Использовать системный каталог:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
   JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE  n.nspname = 'schema_name'
   AND    c.relname = 'table_name'
   AND    c.relkind = 'r'    -- таблицы
   );
```

Ну а далее вам в помощь, `BEGIN.... END` и ответ моего коллеги.

Comment: по хорошему бы вообще процедуру сделать.

Comment: @Yaroslav если это не разовый кейс, беусловно да.

Answer (score 1):

[Вы можете создать таблицу, указав её имя и перечислив все имена столбцов и их типы:](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/tutorial-table)

```
CREATE TABLE weather (
    city            varchar(80),
    temp_lo         int,           -- минимальная температура дня
    temp_hi         int,           -- максимальная температура дня
    prcp            real,          -- уровень осадков
    date            date
);
```

[Таблицу можно переименовать так:](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/ddl-alter#idp11)

```
ALTER TABLE products RENAME TO items;
```